# 3-SAT family with $\omega(n^2)$ time complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

A 3-SAT family is an algorithm that given a positive integer $n$ outputs a 3-SAT problem in $n$ clauses in $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ time ($\epsilon$ is to allow for the indexing of the variables).

A solution of a 3-SAT family is an algorithm that given a positive integer decides whether the corresponding 3-SAT problem is satisfiable.

Can you give an example of a 3-SAT family such that the time complexity of each its solution is $\omega(n^2)$? What about $\omega(n^{3})$ or $\omega(n^{1000})$?

The examples should not depend on $P\neq NP$ or other conjectures.

Comment: OP states $3$-SAT and $n$ clauses and so sparsification lemma (where we require $\Theta(n)$ clauses) is not applicable and so perhaps the problem makes sense.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then it is still wide open. The best known lower bounds that we have on any natural problem in NP are linear.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz Is this mentioned in some paper?

Comment: Here's the current state of the art: https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2021/023/ . It's for circuits, which might not be the model that you're thinking of.